# Make all SELinux contexts permanent

Tags: selinux

I've done a lot of `chcon`-ing lately,but if I understand it correctly, these will be erased on the next relabel. Is there any way to make the current contexts (preferably just under a certain directory) permanent? I understand there's a way to do it using `semanage`, but that means going back through and checking the context of every file and invoking `semanage` to set a rule. So is there some automated way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First up, you are correctin that `semanage fcontext -a -t <type> <filepattern>` makes file changes permanent by adding them to the policy - you'll need to relabel or `restorecon -R -v <filepattern>` to apply those changes. `chcon` does not alter policy, just the on-disk context.

You can generate a list of differences to your labelled policy with [`matchpathcon`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/matchpathcon), specifically:

```
matchpathcon -V /path/to/file
```

Unfortunately it has no recursive option, probably due to the fact that walking the tree would be expensive, but you could drive it with:

```
find / -exec matchpathcon -V {} \;
```

However, be careful. I believe find will traverse all file system mounts including filesystems without extended attributes (xattrs) which might cause problems. Of course, if all your file systems have extended attributes there isn't a problem.

Once you have this list, you could then write a script to pick out those you'll `semanage`. I don't know of an automated way to do this in one hit, however.

Answer (score 3):

Using `matchpathcon` with `find` is very slow.  Why not use `restorecon`?

`restorecon -rnv /path/to/dir`

the flags are recursive, no-changes, and verbose.